# What is the problem with node_modules (or npm) on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-modules, ubuntu-20.04

I started to use Ubuntu last year and since today I face really annoying problems. Firstly the problems were Reactjs with script errors which I couldn't even start a project, anyway I solved in different ways. And now I face problems

1. starting Reactjs with Typescript project like above error and
2. starting Vuejs project.

I googled problems and nothing helped. I don't know how to solve these kinds of problems permanently (I am not experienced on Ubuntu more) but I guess it is probably the wrong path problem in node_modules or npm folders. I checked all the permissions, installed packages with sudo, I don't think it is for a permission issue. But my folder structure looks really dirty, needs cleaning. If you want any more information from the system, I can provide all you want. I would be glad for any help!

My laptop: HP Pavilion g6, Ubuntu 20.04

**React Typescript project trying to start**

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]': Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.8/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.9/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.0/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.2/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/isTypeReadonly.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/adjacent-overload-signatures.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/config-array-factory.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/getESLint.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/linter.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.8/node.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.8/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.9/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.0/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.2/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/isTypeReadonly.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/adjacent-overload-signatures.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/config-array-factory.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/getESLint.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/linter.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ramil/D:/Codes/dev-challanges/todo-app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-scripts start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ramil/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T20_34_08_108Z-debug.log
```

**Vuejs project problem on starting project**

```
> myapp@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at idToPlugin (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:145:14)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:184:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolvePlugins (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:170:10)
    at new Service (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:32:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ramil/D:/Codes/Vue-apps/myapp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c vue-cli-service serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ramil/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T21_04_13_325Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work because of the start command. You could try to change it to `react-scripts start`

Comment: Nope, it is not so simple situation

Comment: It looks like you are missing a couple of modules. You can try to run `npm i` or `yarn` to install them.

Comment: I did. Still same

Comment: So when you run `npm run start` or `yarn start` in the react app you get that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED

1. Changed the name of main folder (D:) from (D) - I don't know it affected or not, but removed symbol.
2. I added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin` to .bashrc file